# Перестал работать парсер chipdip после примерно недели стабильной работы

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Я новичок в парсинге, и мне сложно понять с чем связанно такое поведение сайта, в один момент после недели успешной выгрузки вся программа перестала работать, просто завершает работу без каких либо ошибок, выяснил, что проблема со стороны запроса, но что с этим делать так и не понял, помогите пожалуйста

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("https://www.chipdip.ru/catalog/ic-analog-switch?p.0=Analog+Devices&sort=hits&page=1")

html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for el in html.select(".itemlist.itemlist_main.with-hover"):
    title = el.select_one(".h_name > div")
    title = title.text
    print(title)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow!

Если вывести `r`, то вы сможете увидеть `<Response [403]>`, а если вывести содержание `html`, то вы увидите, что это страница `DDoS-Guard`. Сайт поставил защиту от DDoS-атак, которая фильтрует и запросы вашего скрипта.

Способы обхода этой защиты не в рамках данного ресурса